# Which CSS property can be used for controlling the stretchiness of a control?

Tags: html, css

Which CSS property can be set for controls so that they won't look stretched in any browser? I am concerned about IE, FireFox, and Safari.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger, if you're going to correct the spelling at least add the `i` and turn it into a real word.

Comment: I guess this depends on what HTML control outputs and what is the definition of "streched" (or should I say stretched)?

Comment: @MrXexxed - sorry, the word "stretchiness" temporarily escaped me! Should make more sense now!

Comment: In HTML, a background image of a page can be stretched so that it can be of page width size. In the same way, sometimes controls get stretched to be of some fixed width.
I am not sure if this explaination is enough to clear what exactly I want to say about stretching of a control. Please let me know, if you need any more explaination.

Comment: this doesn't really make sense. Images have a specific aspect ratio; controls have not. Can you show in more detail what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

---

Seriously, though, let's see if I can have a crack at getting you an answer you need.

The word "control" is quite strange here - I'll take it to mean any HTML form element. All form elements will not *stretch* (again, another strange word) to fill up the space given to them, except for the `textarea` element, because they are **inline** level elements, meaning the default `display` value is `inline`. This means that, without adding any code, your form element should not look "stretched" to begin with.

Different browsers have different default width for form elements. If you need them to be of the same width, you have to explicitly set them in your CSS. I hope this answers your questions, though clarifications would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

```
float:left;
```

makes it shrink-wrap
same as `position:absolute;`

but all in all you will need to explain what you mean by stretchness?

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` maybe? It's a pretty vague question to be fair.